# Returning the View Model to a Controller from a Form.Submit client action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel

I have a controller with 2 Index methods:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    viewModel.PipelineIndex pivm = new viewModel.PipelineIndex(null, User.Identity.Name);
    return View(pivm);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(viewModel.PipelineIndex model, FormCollection collection)
{
    viewModel.PipelineIndex pivm = null;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        string key = collection.AllKeys[0];
        string ID = collection.Get(key).ToString();
        pivm = new viewModel.PipelineIndex(ID, User.Identity.Name);
    }
    else
        pivm = new viewModel.PipelineIndex(null, User.Identity.Name);

    return View(pivm);

}
```

The ViewModel I am using is a well defined class:

```
public class PipelineIndex
{
    private Models.Context _db = new Models.Context();

    public List<SelectListItem> GroupList { get; set; }
    public List<string> ButtonCaptions { get; set; }
    public List<ContactDetail> ContactList { get; set; }
    public string PageTitle { get; set; }
    ...
```

The View consumes the ViewModel setting up a Grid and a Drop Down control:

```
@model BlueSkies.Pipeline.ViewModels.PipelineIndex
@{ ViewBag.Title = "Index"; }
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    <h2>@Model.PageTitle</h2>
    <div style="clear:both">
        @if (Model != null)
        {
            var grid = new WebGrid(canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 15, canSort: true, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grid");
            grid.Bind(Model.ContactList, rowCount: Model.ContactList.Count, autoSortAndPage: true);
            grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.All);
            @grid.GetHtml(htmlAttributes: new { id = "grid" },
            columns: grid.Columns(
                grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("View", "Details", "Contacts", new { ID = item.Name }, null)),
                grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Contacts", new { ID = item.Name }, null)),
                grid.Column("Name"),
                grid.Column(columnName: "Phone1", header: "Phone")
            ));
        }
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div>
        @*foreach (string caption in ViewBag.ButtonCaptions)
        { 
            @Html.ActionLink(caption, "Index", "Pipeline", new { ID = caption }, new { @class = "menuSubButton" })
        }*@
        @Html.DropDownList("GroupDropDown", Model.GroupList, new { @onchange = "this.form.submit()" }) &nbsp; Select a pipe section...
    </div>
}
```

Where I am having challenges is when the Drop Down fires the Form.Submit (on the onChange event).  No model is being returned to my Controller.  I do have the FormCollection but I would rather have the *updated* model including the new selectedItem in the drop down.  What am I missing?  And yes, I am looking for a **non-JS** based solution at this point - or as close as I can.  I don't want to AJAX this page.

TIA

NOTE:  There is a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117820/view-model-is-null-when-submitting-using-ajaxsubmit).  It is AJAX based but getting the same null model on call into the controller.  Why is it so hard to find the *right* answer?  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the rendered HTML form will have a select with the name "GroupDropDown", is that right? If so, the selected value will be posted back on submit with that name and would be bound to either a parameter called groupDropDown or to a string property GroupDropDown on your model class. Do you have such a property on your model?

Comment: Added the property to my ViewModel and it does populate correctly.  Now to figure out why the other items in my ViewModel are null.  Possibly because they have not changed?

Comment: Your model will be populated from the data coming back from the browser in the HTTP POST. If you don't put a model property value into some input field in the form you won't get it back with the post, hence it will be null in the action. One technique is to use hidden fields to store values that are otherwise not "visible" in the form as input. If you want to gain a better understanding what is going on, I'd suggest to investigate the HTTP POST data with Fiddler or some other tool to check what values are sent back to your application.

Comment: Ah - the "secret" here is an HTML Input Control.  While the grid can contain input elements, currently it does not.  Got it!

Answer (score 0):

I am mentally exhausted, so I add this disclaimer. Thought Answering a question would get me away from my day.

The business problem appears to be "select one item from drop down and have contents rendered accordingly". If that is correct, there is no need to pass back the entire contents of the View Model; you only need to pass back the id, which is demoed numerous times on many sites.

Am I missing something?

Comment: At this moment no.  Nothing.  As I continue working through this problem space I may be needing more and more of the altered model to "deal with".  Eventually this will be an edit grid and if/when the drop down is changed I will need to submit those changes back to the DB.

Comment: If you come from a more traditional web form methodology, the stateless nature of MVC tends to bite you until you can make the mental paradigm change. I was "lucky" that I did a lot of ASP work in the 90s, so flipping back to a more stateless model was easier than someone who weaned themselves on ASP.NET. MVC is tricky in that it requires you feed it everything. As MVC progresses, however, the team is throwing in more and more implicit features that help coders around this "issue", so I could very well miss something in the mix. ;-)